# Facebook SDK for Unity - Trouble reading friends scores on iOS

Tags: android, ios, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I've come into some trouble, and I'm hoping some of you can point me in the right direction.

I'm programming in Unity3D with the Facebook SDK to use the Scores API.
I have made a scoreboard where you can see your high score, and your friends high score. Just finished my game for Android, and all facebook functionality worked perfectly after it was reviewed on Facebook.

So here is my problem. I just started to test the game out on iOS. So I added the iOS platform to the app on developers.facebook.com. Testing the app on an iOS worked well, until I tested the scoreboard. I created some test users, and could log in, and the high scores were saved to the Scores API after publish actions was aquired.

But whenever I go to the Scoreboard page, all I get is the score of the test user I am logged in to. I tried to look at the response I got from the HttpMethod.GET, and only the user requesting the data was listed in the string, even when he has friends who has also saved their scores on the scores API on the Android app and iOS app. I tried to log in with a user I had previously used on Android, and this user could get the scores of all his friends, but not the scores of his friends who had tested the app on iOS.

I also tested to log in on android with the test user I had used on iOS. He could still see his own score, but none of his friends who had played on iOS nor Android. I don't get it. If I create a test user and log in on the Android app first, then he can see all his friends who has played the app on Android. If I then log in on iOS, he can still see his friends scores who have played on Android. If he had logged in on iOS first, then he would not see any friends, no matter which platform he would login to later.

Anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong here? Since it works perfectly on Android, I suppose it's not Unity code related. More like some setup to get the iOS platform to work properly on Facebook. I am empty of ideas of what could be causing the issue.

Thanks in advance, guys!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I needed the user_friends permission on iOS. On Android, you don't need that permission.